# "Sees" or "Looks at"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Would one of **sees** and **looks at** be more appropriate for this particular context (and if yes, why?) or are they interchangeable?

Nina is standing at a sink desperately trying to wash the wine stains off her dress when a woman enters the bathroom. Nina **sees**/**looks at** her spotless dress.

Nina: Can I buy your dress?

Woman: Excuse me?

Nina: Can I buy your dress? How much do you want?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of *agency*. Generally, *look [at]* is a deliberate act, whereas *see* is merely a consequence of an object being in view.

The word 'see' does get misused, though: People say *Come and see this!* when, technically, they should say *Come and look at this!*.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my intuition but I understand that

In ***Nina sees the dress*** the emphasis lies on the action of seeing.

In ***Nina looks at the dress*** the emphasis is on the fact that during this action something makes her think and make a decision which is made clear in the rest of your context.

If i were the author, I would prefer to use ***looks at***, it is more intense.

Comment: You can see something by chance if you happen to turn your eyes towards it, but you can only look at something deliberately.